# How do I change multiple elements with the same class to a list of array items

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, class, web

Basically, I have multiple elements with the same class name, what I am doing is fetching an array of integers from an API, I want to loop through all the elements with this class name and change each one to one of the elements from the array in order.
For example

```
<p class="test">hello</p>
<p class="test">hello</p>
<p class="test">hello</p>
<p class="test">hello</p>
```

and the array looks like this
[1,5,2,11]
after the loop, things should look like this

```
<p class="test">1</p>
<p class="test">5</p>
<p class="test">2</p>
<p class="test">11</p>
```

Thank you)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through the array indexes. Then use that index to access the corresponding array elements and DOM elements.

```
const array = [1, 5, 2, 11];
const paras = document.getElementsByClassName("test");

array.forEach((val, i) => paras[i].innerText = val;
```